# How do I prevent code from creating instances of a base class?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, inheritance

Let's say I created `Circle` and `Triangle` classes inherited from `Shape` class. My question is how do I prevent code from creating instances of the `Shape` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make the Shape class **abstract**. That means it is an unfinished class serving as base for other classes that supply the additional functionality.

For instance, if you have sever classes that load data, you could have an abstract class *DataLoader* and concrete classes *DatabaseLoader*, *XmlLoader* ...

Comment: How you make a class abstract is language dependent, but this is the correct general answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give Shape a protected constructor. Circle and Triangle can still call those from their own constructors. But others cannot.

Dante Jinag is ofcourse right for Java, I was assuming C++

Answer (score 1):

You can make Shape class as **abstract**.

```
public abstract class Shape {

//your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What programming language you're using?

In general object creation is memory allocation for it members and call of constructor. If your Shape class didn't have a members - no memory will allocated. And if it has empty constructor - also nothing will happend at this step.